# Padding In bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

Im using bootstrap:

```
<div id="main" class="container" role="main">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <h2>Welcome</h2>
        <p>Hello and welcome to my website.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        Image Here (TODO)
    </div>
</div>
```

Main also has a grey background. The background of the page is white. The problem I am having is that the text is right to the edge of the grey background. I want some padding but when I add it in, the image span goes to the next line.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have not used Bootstrap but I worked on Zurb Foundation. On that I used to add space like this.

```
<div id="main" class="container" role="main">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="span5 offset1">
            <h2>Welcome</h2>
            <p>Hello and welcome to my website.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            Image Here (TODO)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Visit this link: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html and read the section: Offsetting columns.

I think I know what you are doing wrong. If you are applying padding to the `span6` like this:

```
<div class="span6" style="padding-left:5px;">
    <h2>Welcome</h2>
    <p>Hello and welcome to my website.</p>
</div>
```

It is wrong. What you have to do is add padding to the elements inside:

```
<div class="span6">
    <h2 style="padding-left:5px;">Welcome</h2>
    <p  style="padding-left:5px;">Hello and welcome to my website.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers but this is not what im after.

Comment: @plaidcorp Offset class is used to shift columns not add padding to the inner elements in that column

Comment: @DawoodAwan Long story short: I didn't properly read the question (I had another agenda). You're correct and the logic in the answer still holds.

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion from @Dawood is good if that works for you.

If you need more fine-tuning than that, one option is to use padding on the text elements, here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/FtBwe/

**CSS**

```
p, h2 {
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are padding built into various classes.

For example:

A asp.net web forms app:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkShowDeletedServers" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Text="Show Deleted" />
```

this code above would place the Text of "Show Deleted" too close to the checkbox to what I see at nice to look at.

However with bootstrap

```
<div class="checkbox-inline">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkShowDeletedServers" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Text="Show Deleted" />
</div>
```

This created the space, if you don't want the text bold,  that class=checkbox

Bootstrap is very flexible, so in this case I don't need a hack, but sometimes you need to.