# Padding not working properly in Mobile-View with Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

So, I’m work in Bootstrap padding work properly as expected in `Web-View`,
But in `Mobile-View` padding not work as expected,
I’m using class `"col-sm-offset-3 col-md-3"` for Dropdown and
`col-sm-2  padding5px` for button.

I want padding between dropdown and button in `Mobile-View`.

Where is the problem I’m not find out.

**Web-View image:**

[image]

**Mobile-View image:**

[image]

**Here is the code:**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-md-3">
            <select id="ddlDownload" class="form-control"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2  padding5px">
            <button id="btnDownload" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="DownloadFile()">Download</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please show use our code from the `padding5px` css class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Padding and bootstrap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134089/padding-and-bootstrap)

Answer (score 2):

by default in bootstrap there is no top and bottom padding and margin between cols you need to add custom padding or margin by css you can try code below

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-md-3">
            <select id="ddlDownload" class="form-control"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-top:5px">
            <button id="btnDownload" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="DownloadFile()">Download</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want to add inline css ( style attribute ). you can add the following code in you css file

```
#btnDownload{ 
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

or for padding

```
#btnDownload{
  padding-top:5px;
}
```

hope this will work